# Division by zero in

Tags: php

I was looking through my PHP logs and found an error stating there is `Division by zero` in one of my files on the line I posted below. Does anyone know why this would cause that ?

```
        $dataTableHTML .= "<tr>";
        $dataTableHTML .= "<td class=\"center\">" . $label . "</td>";
        $dataTableHTML .= "<td class=\"center\">" . $dataRev[$k] . "</td>";
        $dataTableHTML .= "<td class=\"center mobileHide\">" . round(($dataRev[$k] / $totalVisits) * 100, 1) . "%</td>";
        $dataTableHTML .= "</tr>";
```

Comment: The only way that's possible is if `$totalVists` is 0 ... so, is it?

Comment: If it is, you may want to check that case beforehand and set the result to 0, only make the actual calculation if it is > 0 (assuming it cannot be < 0, but that should be checked right from the start).

Comment: As there is only one division in the code presented, it's unclear what you are asking for: "Division by zero" is quite clear.

Comment: the error is self explanatory isn't it? $totalVisits gest 0 at some point so u need to consider that situation in ur logic somehow

Answer (score 1):

it is possible only if $totalVisits equals 0. Сarefully review the case when there may be 0

```
$dataRev[$k] / $totalVisits
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned the 'division by zero' is raised if `$totalVisits == 0`. You can configure your code with this line:

```
$dataTableHTML .= "<td class=\"center mobileHide\">" . 
                   (($totalVisits != 0) ? round(($dataRev[$k] / $totalVisits) * 100, 1) : "0") .
                  "%</td>";
```

What I have modified is a verification if `$totalVisits != 0`. In that case it performs and returns the calculation. Otherwise it returns `"0"`. If you want another value, such as `"N/A"`, simply replace the text.